# Confusion in proof of a lemma.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, complex-analysis

[image]

In the above proof I can't understand why $|\psi_j||\psi_l| - \psi_k \bar \psi_l$ has positive real part unless $\psi_k \bar \psi_l \geq 0$ for every pair $j,l$.

Help Needed!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is being asserted is very simple: let $c$ and $d$ be two complex numbers. Then $\Re (c \bar{d}) \leq |c| |d|$ and equality holds only when $c \bar{d}$ is a non negative number. To see this write $z=c\bar {d}$. The fact that $\Re z \leq |z|$ is clear. Suppose equality holds. Write $a=\Re z, b=\Im z$. Then $a=|z|$. Hence $a^{2} =|z|^{2}=a^{2}+b^{2}$ which gives $b=0$. Hence $z=a=|z|$ so $z \geq 0$.

Comment: how do you define a complex number to be $\geq 0$?

Comment: A complex number is $\geq 0$ if its imaginary part is 0 and real part is $\geq 0$.